# How to enable command js> shell in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, shell, firefox

The command js> should be native versions of the nightly builds of Firefox(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell). But when I open the terminal firefox it says that this command is not recognized. How to activate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not included in the Firefox Nightly builds, but produced during the build and made available as [a separate download](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/) (`jsshell*`).

Get the file corresponding to your OS, unzip and run in a terminal:

```
jsshell-mac $ ./js 
js> 1 + 2
3
```